# Designing a program that calls a function in a loop

Tags: java, function, for-loop

This week's problem in my beginner CSC class has me a little confused or just unsure of myself.

Problem:

> Design a function named "fallingDistance" that accepts an object's
>   falling time (in seconds) as an argument. The function should return
>   the distance, in meters, that the object has fallen during that time
>   interval. Design a program that calls the function in a loop that
>   passes the values 1 through 10 as arguments and displays the return
>   value.

Here's my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    for(int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
    {
        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#,##,###.00");

        //Print
        System.out.println(" Time (in seconds): " + i + "\t" + " Distance fallen (meters): " + df.format(fallingDistance(i)) + " meters");
    }
    //Function
    public static double fallingDistance(int fallTime)
    {
        //Formula is d = 1/2gt^2
        double a = 0.5, gravity = 9.8, distance;

        distance = (a * gravity) * (Math.pow(fallTime, 2.0));
        return distance;
    }
}
```

The hangup I have is in regards to the "calls the function in a loop." Unless I'm misunderstanding, the program is functioning properly as is?

Comment: Yes, you are calling the ***method*** inside of the for loop. What exactly is your question?  Suggestion: 1) take the DecimalFormat object creation outside of the loop. No need to keep re-creating the same object ***inside*** of the loop when you can simply have it created once ***before*** the loop. 2) Work to improve your code formatting, especially your indentation. Good formatting is not for looks but is to make it easier for you (and ***us***) to understand your code and debug your code.

Comment: @keshlam: his equations look OK to me. The `i` variable represents time, and this should increase linearly.

Comment: Is there a certain format that's expected or is it just something that makes it easier to understand as you said?  I'll definitely make it a point to improve the formatting, rather create a good habit now since I've been doing this for just 4 weeks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're doing what is asked from you. 
( "for(...)" is the loop, "fallingDistance(...)" the function and you're calling the function from inside the loop )

Comment: Thank you for explaining it like this.  For some reason it wasn't making sense in regards to the calling of the function within the loop until your short explanation cleared it up